# Why test $? -eq 0 is true even when I expect it to be false

Tags: shell-script

still struggling with this shell script (Password Validation), I've search for the solution, but I'm still not find the proper solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "enter the password"
read password

len="${#password}"

if test $len -ge 8 ; then
    echo "$password" | grep -q [A-Z]
    echo "$password" | grep -q [a-z]
    echo "$password" | grep -q [0-9]

    if test $? -eq 0 ; then
      echo "Strong password"
    else
      echo "Weak password"
    fi

else
    echo "password lenght should be greater than or equal 8"
fi
```

Were the result from this script as following :

```
# ./password.sh 
enter the password
12345678
Strong password >> Not as I expected which is should be weak password
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: `$?` only gives the return value of the latest command executed

Comment: @user4556274 could you elaborate?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a more specific/descriptive title.

Comment: simple fix: replace the entire script with `echo here is your password: $(pwgen -n 16 -c -0 -y -B 1)`.  or use `makepasswd`. or randomly select 4-6 (or more) words >= 5 chars each from /usr/share/dict/words and join them together with 1-3 digit numbers, punctuation symbols, and/or spaces.  if your users have a habit of choosing weak passwords, then don't let them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `grep` invocations are being ran sequentially and `$?` is only equal to the last `grep` in your script. You'll want to use something like this after each `grep`:

```
retCodes=0
echo "$password" | grep -q "[A-Z]"
retCodes=$(($retCodes + $?))

echo "$password" | grep -q "[a-z]"
retCodes=$(($retCodes + $?))

echo "$password" | grep -q "[0-9]"
retCodes=$(($retCodes + $?))
```

The `if [[ $retCodes -eq 0 ]]; then ...`

Comment: If I was designing such a system as part of a "password change" tester then I'd want to give more feedback to the user ("Must have a capital letter", "Must have a lower case letter" etc).  The structure written here would allow for this with some minor rewrites.

Comment: If you do that you'll probably want to branch off `$?` after each `grep` invocation and just do a `retCodes=$(( $retCodes + 1))` at the end of each if statement's body so that you could perform some generic action at the end of the whole script.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- Using `read` without `-r` makes it difficult to have `\` in the password.
- Not quoting the regular expressions will make the shell treat them as globbing patterns and they will expand to filenames.
- The `$?` variable will only hold the exit status of the last `grep`.

Consider the following *`bash`* script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "password:" -s password

if (( ${#password} < 8 )); then
  echo "Passwords need 8 or more characters"
  exit 1
fi

has_upcase=0
has_locase=0
has_digit=0
has_other=0

case "$password" in
  *[[:upper:]]*) has_upcase=1 ;;&
  *[[:lower:]]*) has_locase=1 ;;&
  *[[:digit:]]*) has_digit=1  ;;&
  *[^[:alnum:]]*) has_other=1 ;;
esac

if (( !has_upcase )); then
  echo "Make sure you password has at least one upper-case letter"
elif (( !has_locase )); then
  echo "Make sure your password has at least one lower-case letter"
elif (( !has_digit )); then
  echo "Make sure your password has at least one digit"
elif (( !has_other )); then
  echo "Make sure your password has at least non-alphanumeric character"
else
  echo "Your password is ok"
fi
```

I took the liberty of adding a "non-alphanumeric" requirement to the testing.

The `read` of `bash` is able to give the user a prompt, and to read while not echoing what is typed.

The `case` statement checks whether the entered password contains at least one upper-case, one lower-case, one numerical, and one non-alphanumeric character (using [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class)).  The funky looking `;;&` at the end of each line there means "continue testing the next pattern with this string".

To get a POSIX `sh` variant of this, replace the `read` with

```
stty -echo
printf "password: "
read -r password
stty echo
printf "\n"
```

And the `case` statement with something like

```
case "$password" in *[[:upper:]]*) has_upcase=1 ;; esac
case "$password" in *[[:lower:]]*) has_locase=1 ;; esac
case "$password" in *[[:digit:]]*) has_digit=1  ;; esac
case "$password" in *[^[:alnum:]]*) has_other=1 ;; esac
```

The rest should still be POSIX.

Comment: +1 for `read -r`; I wish more people would use that.  Shouldn't the `;;` just be `;&` ?

Comment: @StephenHarris `&;` would just fall through to the next statement in the `case` without testing the next pattern. `;;&` tests the next pattern for the same string. `;;` would exit the `case` at a match.

Comment: Ah; a difference between `ksh` and `bash` according to the manuals!  Subtle...

Comment: @StephenHarris `;;` and `;&` seems to be the same in `bash` and `ksh93`, but `ksh93` doesn't have the `;;&` to continue pattern matching.

Comment: Might be worth highlighting your change of sh to bash, in order to use ${# for length

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's POSIX `sh` but  `read -s -p`, and `case ... ;;&` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "enter the password"
read -r password

caps="$(echo "$password" | sed 's/[^A-Z]//g')"
lowers="$(echo "$password" | sed 's/[^a-z]//g')"
numbers="$(echo "$password" | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')"

if [ "${#password}" -lt 8 ]; then
    echo "password lenght should be greater than or equal 8"
else
    echo "caps=${#caps} lowers=${#lowers} numbers=${#numbers}"
    if [ "${#caps}" -ge 1 ] && [ "${#lowers}" -ge 1 ] && [ "${#numbers}" -ge 1 ]; then
        echo "Strong password"
    else
        echo "Weak password"
    fi
fi
```